# How to get the last modified rows from the product inventory

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product inventory log table (see below). Every time a product's stock quantity is changed, a row with its current stock amount is added to the table.

So...

- How can I know how much and what products was in the inventory at the specified time?
- Is it possible know this with one query?
- How about without joins or subqueries?

Log table:

```
row_id  quantity    time                product_id
2413407 1           2016-09-16 13:16:48 122559
2413408 3696        2016-09-16 20:46:42 121152
2413409 3697        2016-09-16 20:46:45 121152
2413410 786         2016-09-16 20:46:47 121152
2413411 3           2016-09-16 20:53:19 128034
2413412 1           2016-09-16 20:53:20 143362
2413413 2           2016-09-16 20:53:30 128051
```

For example using timestamp 2016-09-16 20:46:46 I'd like to get out these rows (because this was the exact inventory at that moment):

```
row_id  quantity    time                product_id
2413407 1           2016-09-16 13:16:48 122559
2413409 3697        2016-09-16 20:46:45 121152
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need subqueries or joins.  Here is one way:

```
select l.*
from log l
where l.time = (select max(l2.time)
                from log l2
                where l2.product_id = l.product_id and
                      l2.time <= '2016-09-16 20:46:46'
               );
```

I should not have said that.  There is at least one way to get this without `join` or subqueries:

```
select product_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(row_id order by time desc), ',', 1) as row_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(quantity order by time desc), ',', 1) as quantity,
       max(time)
from log l
where l.time <= '2016-09-16 20:46:46'
group by product_id;
```

This method is a bit dangerous because the intermediate `group_concat()` string is limited to 1,024 bytes.  This is a session setting that can easily be changed.  In addition, this turns the other columns (`quantity` and `row_id`) into strings.

Finally, I think the original version is faster with the right index `log(product_id, time)`.  But it is possible to meet your conditions.

Comment: :D Yeah, I'm trying to get the most powerful version. Maybe I should just use your first version. I was maybe thinking about something like "row_number() over partition()" thing, but that doesn't exists in mysql, I suppose.

Comment: @viljun . . . If you wanted to do this with `row_number()` you would still need a subquery or CTE.